# SPF softfailing?

Tags: php, email, server

I am getting this when sending from our mail server (mail.XXXX.com) POP.

```
 Received-SPF: softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning rasmus@XXXX.com does not designate 88.99.12.102 as permitted sender)
client-ip=88.99.12.102;


Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
   spf=softfail (google.com: domain of transitioning rasmus@XXXX.com does not designate 88.99.12.102 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=rasmus@XXXX.com;
   dmarc=fail (p=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=XXXX.com
```

Here is our TXT record

```
v=spf1 a ip4:88.99.12.102 include:mailgun.org include:_spf.google.com -all
```

What am i doing wrong? outlook, gmail and other services detects it as SPAM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the looks of your SPF I don't see anything wrong, I have a feeling that it's not using the SPF record you indicated. Because it's "Soft Failing" and based on the SPF Record you are displaying it should "Hard Fail".

Without the full email header, no one is going to be able to help you determine what's going on, the best thing you can do is send an email to this [mail tester](https://www.unlocktheinbox.com/mail-tester/) and see where it says your SPF record is located in DNS. I bet it's not what you think it is.